# Django : ValueError at form submission, returned none

Tags: python, django, forms, web

I'm working on password change form where take old password, new password and confirm new password. If old password does not match with current user's password, it display error message. Also, if new password and password confirm does not match each other, it displays error message. So far I keep getting error messages and I want to know which part went wrong. Why does it return none?

error message

```
ValueError at /blog/password_change/blue/
   The view blog.views.password_change didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^password_change/(?P<username>[-\w.]+)/$', views.password_change, name='password_change'),
url(r'^password_change_done/$', views.password_change_done, name='password_change_done'),
```

forms.py

```
class PasswordChangeForm(SetPasswordForm):
error_messages = dict(SetPasswordForm.error_messages, **{
    'password_incorrect': ("Your old password was entered incorrectly. Please enter it again."),
})
oldpassword = forms.CharField(
    label=("Old password"),
    strip=False,
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autofocus': True}),
)

field_order = ['oldpassword', 'password1', 'password2']

def clean_oldpassword(self):
    oldpassword = self.cleaned_data["oldpassword"]
    if not self.user.check_password(oldpassword):
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['password_incorrect'],
            code='password_incorrect',
        )
    return oldpassword
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def password_change(request, username):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():            
           oldpassword = form.cleaned_data.get('oldpassword')
           password1 = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
           password2 = form.cleaned_data.get('password2')
           if password1 == password2:
               update_session_auth_hash(request, form.username)
               form.save()
               return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/password_change_done/') 
           else:
               return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', {'error_message': 'password mismatch'})

    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
        return redirect(reverse('blog:profile', args=[form.user.get_username()]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your view to below code

```
@login_required
def password_change(request, username):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():            
           oldpassword = form.cleaned_data.get('oldpassword')
           password1 = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
           password2 = form.cleaned_data.get('password2')
           if password1 == password2:
               update_session_auth_hash(request, form.username)
               form.save()
               return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/password_change_done/') 
           else:
              return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', {'error_message': 'password mismatch'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', {'error_messages': form.errors })

else:
    form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
    return redirect(reverse('blog:profile', args=[form.user.get_username()]))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have your redirect and render the wrong way round; you should redirect on success, and render on failure.

Your actual problem though is caused by wrong indentation; if the request is POST but the form is not valid, there is no return statement. You should unindent the final line - which should be the render - so that this case hits that line.

Comment: This is another issue, but once I changed code upon your suggestion, it seems like form become not valid... Do you know why?